# auto download the php script of the destination url

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script that will open a child window every time I click a button. The problem is, it downloads the PHP script. How to prevent auto downloading of the PHP script if the child window is open? Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample code that will open the new window.

```
    <script> 
    $('#btnShow').click(function(){
    var myLog = document.getElementById('txtLog').value;   
   window.open("/sample/sample.php?login="+myLog,"child","width=800,height=600");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: $('#btnShow').click(function(){ var myLog = document.getElementById('txtLog').value; window.open("/sample/sample.php?login="+myLog,"child","width=800,height=600"); }

Comment: are you running the php file in a server?